# Are all computable numbers constructable after a countable number of steps?

Tags: computability, geometric-construction

While looking at another question on this site about constructable numbers I started wondering.  If you can take a countable number of steps (possibly infinite) can you draw an interval of a length corresponding to a computable number?

More strictly if I have a unit interval, a straight edge, a compass, a finite list of instructions (which can include instructions to repeat sequences of the instructions until an event occurs, instructions to draw lines using my tools and instructions on labeling points) and the ability to carry out a countably infinite number of actions in a finite time.  Can I construct a interval that corresponds to a given computable number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can take an infinite number of steps you construct a non-constructible length?

**No.** If you take infinitely many steps, you never finish drawing and hence you cannot draw what you want.

However, you might want to ask whether you can draw successive approximations that get arbitrarily close to the desired drawing (such as a segment with its length being a certain value relative to a given unit segment). In that case...

**It depends.** If you just ask for the existence of a sequence of successive approximations, then...

**Yes even for non-computable numbers**. Any real number has such a sequence because every real number is the limit of some sequence of rational numbers, and all rational numbers are constructible (by compass and straightedge).

But if you ask for the existence of a **computable** sequence of approximations then...

**Yes only for computable numbers**. Every computable number is **by definition** produced digit by digit by a procedure, and every time you get a new digit you can construct the corresponding approximation that is accurate to that digit. It can certainly be done because the approximations are all rational. Conversely, if you have a computable sequence of approximations that converge to a length, then clearly the limit is computable.

Comment: instead of "yes even for non-computable numbers" you mean't yes even for definable non-computable numbers (such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant )

Comment: Note that you can computably approach non-computable reals - for example, let $r_n=\sum_{i=0}^nd(i, n)$, where $d(i, n)=0$ if the $i$th Turing machine on input $i$ does not halt in $<n$ steps, and $d(i)=2^{-i}$ otherwise. Then $\lim r_n$ is a noncomputable real, but the sequence $\{r_n\}$ is uniformly computable.

Comment: @user1952009: It doesn't have to be definable; any real number is the limit of a sequence of rationals, whether or not we can define the sequence!

Comment: @user21820 it is not 100% true. every definable real number is the limit of a definable sequence of rationals. every un-definable real number is NOT the limit of any definable sequence of rationals. and every definable rational is computable, but many definable (infinite) sequences of rationals are not, and many (infinite) sequences of rationals are not even definable.

Comment: @user1952009: What are you saying? I never said that undefinable real numbers are the limit of a definable sequence of rationals!

Comment: ok, but definable or not changes everything in that context

Comment: @user1952009: That's my point; the asker has to be very precise about what exactly he/she wants. I think the question is meant to be about computable approximations anyway, so definability is irrelevant haha..

Comment: his question is not precise, but is clearly related to the definability and computability problem

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Given the updated question, I think the answer is "no", because we cannot test equality of points using geometric constructions, but at the moment I don't see an easy way to prove it...

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly define a (possibly infinite) sequence of segments whose total length has as its limit any computable number.  You can compute the binary expansion of the number.  The integer part is easy, just add up the proper number of $1$'s.  Then add on $\frac 1{2^n}$ if the $n^{\text{th}}$ bit of the expansion is $1$.  This will give you the correct limit.

Comment: Wouldn't that require an infinitely large instruction list?  The only modifable memory I have is my drawing space.

Comment: @QthePlatypus: Hey not fair! You changed your question!

Comment: Sorry.  It wasn't clear what I was asking for.